# No network connection when connecting to server directly to router, connections over switch work

Tags: linux, networking, router, ethernet

### Situation/Build

First of all i build a small home server for storage proposes. It runs on Linux. Ubuntu 20.04.3 with Kernel 5.13 (HWE) enabled to be more specific. I used a [MSI MPG B460I Gaming Edge WIFI](https://de.msi.com/Motherboard/MPG-B460I-GAMING-EDGE-WIFI/Specification). I will call it NAS to keep it simple. Normally, Ubuntu 20.04.3 comes with Kernel 5.4 but after booting up i recognised my ethernet interface card an RTL8125 is not listed when using

```
ip -a
```

After googling around, i found out, that kernel 5.4 does not support RTL8125 so i upgraded it to 5.13 and after a reboot it appeared and i configured it with a static ip address. So far so good.
To install it, i connected it to a [5-Port D-Link Switch](https://eu.dlink.com/de/de/products/dgs-105-5-port-gigabit-ethernet-switch) which is located on my desk. This Switch is connected to my [FritzBox 7360](https://www.bedienungsanleitu.ng/avm/fritz-box-7360/anleitung) which i use as a central access point for my local network at home. Everything works perfectly.

### Problem

After building, installing and setting everthing up i wanted to change the location of my NAS and connect it directly to my FritzBox. After booting i recognized, that leds on the ethernet port are turned off and no network connecting could be established. So i brought it back on my desk and connected it to my swtich and it worked perfectly fine.

### Approaches

- connect my NAS with another port on my switch, ethernet port remains turned off
- tested both ports on my FritzBox wih my notebooks (Windows 10, Arch-Linux) which are working perfectly fine
- tried multiple operating systems with different kernels (Debian 11 - 5.11, Opensuse Leap 15.3 - 5.3, Ubuntu 20.04.3 -  5.13 (HWE))
- switching between dhcp or static ip on my NAS
- connected my laptop and my NAS directly which also leads to an active ethernet port
- I can use any port on my 5-Port for connecting my NAS and it can connct to my home network

For all tests I used the same network cable, because multiple connections with different devices are working fine with the same cable.

### Idea

My Fritzbox uses a 100Mbit connection and my NAS can use up too 2.5 Gbit. But this should not be the problem at all, because Eternet Standards are backward compatible?
Does anyone of you have experienced a similar problem?

### tldr;

- NAS connects to local network:

  - ROUTER -> SWITCH -> NAS
- NAS does not connect to local network (ethernet ports leds remain turned off):

  - ROUTER -> NAS

Comment: You state that the same crossover cable was used for all testing. Well might it be that the failing connection simply doesn't work with that one, e.g. the NAS and ROUTER cannot negotiate the link to a working state. Some kind of hardware problem in the interconnection between these two devices maybe.

Comment: Is there any trick i can do to detect those interconnection problems?

Comment: As indicated above, swap out the cable.

Comment: Touché. I already swapped the cable with another one. I meant on system level like a log file or something. i guess [tcpdump](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/tcpdump) does only work after the connection is established?

Comment: Check system logs; e.g. `dmseg | less` to begin with... e.g. `ls -l /var/log` for more to look into,

Comment: I suspect this may be an ethernet speed negotiation issue.  Maybe you can use ethtool to force the appropriate speed/duplex? IMHO Realtek cards can be very tempremental - especially under Linux.

Comment: this seems to be the reason. Logs are showing the this behaviour. Since only 2 of 4 ethernet ports on my router are 1Gbit connections. I decided to wire my NAS to one of the 1Gbits ports and it works out of the box. So reinstalled/rewired my whole local network, but i reached my goal. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is stumpling about this here is my solution:

(re-)wire the whole network so your board with the RTL8125 is connected via 1GiB/s Ethernet connection.
Check if your router supports it and check if it is enabled. On my router only 100Mbits was enabled on all ethernet ports.
Maybe it is possible to force a 100Mbit/s connection with ethtool or something but at the end this seems not a handy solution because all devices can read and write with max 12,5MByte/s from my storage which seems slow and outdated in 2022.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).